# nested dict python keys

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, key

I want something like following structure : `y['1'][tuple(list)] = val` 
as an nested dict in python but while i am trying i get `KeyError` :

data in csv file is like :

```
Rest_id, rates, items
1,4, burger
1,8, tofu_log
2,5, burger
2,8.5, tofu_log
3,4, chef_salad
3,8, steak_salad_sandwich
4,5, steak_salad_sandwich,salad
4,2.5, wine_spritzer
5,4, extreme_fajita3,test2,test4,test
5,8, fancy_european_water
6,5, fancy_european_water
6,6,  extreme_fajita, jalapeno_poppers, extra_salsa
7,1.5, wine_spritzer
7,5, extreme_fajita, jalapeno_poppers
```

following is the code :

```
y = defaultdict(dict)

with open('sample_data_tested_with.csv','r') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
            reader = [[x.strip() for x in row] for row in reader]
            for i in reader:
                #cd[i[0]] = {tuple(i[2:]):i[1]}
                #cd[i[0]][tuple(i[2:])].update(i[1])
                print i[0], i[1], tuple(i[2:])
                y[i[0]][tuple(i[2:])].append(i[1])
```

Later I want to search in the dict like `y['rest_id']['item']` and find rates for that.
Thanks in advance.

full stack from ipython :

```
 In [49]: with open('sample_data_tested_with.csv','r') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
            reader = [[x.strip() for x in row] for row in reader]
            for i in reader:
                #cd[i[0]] = {tuple(i[2:]):i[1]}
                #cd[i[0]][tuple(i[2:])].update(i[1])
                print i[0], i[1], tuple(i[2:])
                #x[tuple(i[2:])]=float(i[1])
                y[i[0]][tuple(i[2:])].append(i[1])
   ....:         
 1 4 ('burger',)
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-49-ab608c2dc33a> in <module>()
       7                     print i[0], i[1], tuple(i[2:])
       8                     #x[tuple(i[2:])]=float(i[1])
 ----> 9                     y[i[0]][tuple(i[2:])].append(i[1])
       10 

  KeyError: ('burger',)
```

Comment: i could have y = defaultdict(list) and append data but then im not able to search data based on the keys like : y['rest_id']['item']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you could use [itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```
>>>import itertools
>>>newreader,keys=[],[]
>>>for k,g in itertools.groupby(reader,key=lambda x:x[0]):
      newreader.append(tuple(g[1:]))
      keys.append(k)
```

This should group your data into tuples.
Now we iterate through newreader converting each tuple into a dict.

```
>>>d={}
>>>for *i,j in newreader,keys:
     d[j]=dict(i)
```

Comment: I am getting following error now :  ValueError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-145e6ba39c9a> in <module>()
----> 1 for i,j in newreader,keys:
      2     d[j] = dict(i)
      3 

ValueError: too many values to unpack

Comment: @snehalparmar thanks for the feedback, let me check.

Comment: @snehalparmar could you edit in the output your print statement gives into your original question?

Comment: @snehalparmar does the updated code work? I am using Cpython so I don't know if this is implementation specific.

Comment: @snehalparmar check now. if not, then I got nothing.

Comment: Thanks i got it working, will update my answer here soon

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution i got, please check and let know if anyones find any issues with it, thanks a lot.

```
def create_NestedDict(filename):
    NestedDict = defaultdict(dict)
    with open(filename,'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
            #print "row :", row
            record = row
            if record[0] not in NestedDict:
                NestedDict[record[0]] = {}
            items = tuple([ i.strip() for i in record[2:]])
            [record[0]][items] = record[1]
    return NestedDict
```